# Set the value of an input via dev tools such that Angular recognizes it?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to streamline a bit of work within GA4 where I have a set of dimensions to create for a long list of GA4 properties. Navigating to the Custom definitions screen, I have a script I run in the dev tools console that is set up to simply click/type what I would typically do by hand.

However, after executing the code, the page doesn't recognize that the field was changed, and some kind of validation doesn't execute, so the save button remains disabled. Further, if I then click into the field, form field validation shows an error, but copy and pasting the same text resolves the issue.

[image: Disabled Save Button]

Here's the relevant portion of the code I'm running:

```
document.querySelector('button.create-definition-button').click();
document.querySelector('definition-builder input.custom-name-control').value = dimensions[i].customName;
```

I've attempted to further emulate what I do by hand by trying any mix of the following types of things:

```
document.querySelector('definition-builder input.custom-name-control').click();
document.querySelector('definition-builder input.custom-name-control').blur();
document.querySelector('definition-builder input.custom-name-control').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

Unfortunately with no luck. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have this resolved, but didn't take the time to figure out what event was actually needed. In short, within dev tools, I ran the following:

```
monitorEvents(el)
```

Then interacted with the form field in the way that passes validation manually, then sifted through all the events that displayed as a result of that interaction. Note that you can probably [hone in on the events that are more probable](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#monitorevents) to log less.

Nuclear option, just to get it done:

```
el.dispatchEvent(new Event("focus"));
el.dispatchEvent(new Event("pointerup"));
el.dispatchEvent(new Event("mouseup"));
el.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));
el.dispatchEvent(new Event("keydown"));
el.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
el.dispatchEvent(new Event("keyup"));
el.dispatchEvent(new Event("keypress"));
el.dispatchEvent(new Event("textInput"));
el.dispatchEvent(new Event("blur"));
```

And that worked!